# Add multiple future dates at one time into redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, union, amazon-redshift

Now I have a table that with the detail as follows:

```
Date    Campaign      Visits   Orders    Revenue
....     ....         ....     ....       ....
Jun-18   Promotion01   10        1        120
```

Let's say it called table A
Now because of report purpose, I would like to add in new dates like as follows

```
Date    Campaign      Visits   Orders    Revenue
Jul-18     NULL         0       0         0
Aug-18     NULL         0       0         0
Sep-18     NULL         0       0         0
....       ....         ....     ....       ....
Dec-18     NULL         0       0         0
```

I would like to use the union to add in only the date data.
I tried the dateadd function in Amazon redshift with the following command

```
SELECT 
    to_char(dateadd(month, 18, '01-01-2017'),'yyyy-MM') as plus30,
    NULL,
    0,
    0,
    0
```

It returns the date, however it just return only 1 row i.e

```
Date    Campaign      Visits   Orders    Revenue
Jul-18     NULL         0       0         0
```

If I want to return multiple row like how it is shown before, except of joining 1 by 1, what should I do then?
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the easiest way to do these sorts of tasks is to make an Excel spreadsheet, fill-in all the desired values, save it as CSV and then use COPY to load it into Redshift. This gives you the benefit of a nice interface to create the data without having to play around with SQL.

The reason you are only getting one line is that SELECT normally works off a table of data, returning one result per row of input data. You have not specified a table, so it is returning only one row.

Fortunately, you can use `generate_series()` in some situation to simulate data:

```
SELECT 
    to_char(date '01-01-2017' + counter * interval '1 month','yyyy-MM') as plus30,
    NULL,
    0,
    0,
    0
FROM generate_series(1, 12) as counter
```

This generates:

```
2017-02 (null)  0   0   0
2017-03 (null)  0   0   0
2017-04 (null)  0   0   0
2017-05 (null)  0   0   0
2017-06 (null)  0   0   0
2017-07 (null)  0   0   0
2017-08 (null)  0   0   0
2017-09 (null)  0   0   0
2017-10 (null)  0   0   0
2017-11 (null)  0   0   0
2017-12 (null)  0   0   0
2018-01 (null)  0   0   0
```

(Your question showed `yyyy-MM` in the SQL, but `Mon-YY` in the output, so please adjust accordingly. It is normally better to use `yyyy-MM` because it is easily sortable as both a number and a string.)